# How to convert AJAX response to JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I trying to manipulate my AJAX response.

[image]

I need to create a foreach to create cards with the search results.This is my code:

```
$('#OrdAlf').on("click", function(){
  var value = $(this).data("value");
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: theme_url + '/helpers/filter_index.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "text",
    data: {ordFilter:value}
  }).done(function(data){
    //console.log();
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    alert(json);
    var htmlLoad = '<div class="draggable ui-widget-content card-crm" id="card-crm"><div class="avatar-client"></div><div class="info-content"><p class="name">'+data+'</p><p class="info-contact"></p><p class="when-enter"><span class="ico-enter"></span></p></div><div class="icons-top"></div><div class="clear"></div></div></b>';
    var ajax_load = "<img src='https://i.imgur.com/FpzX0YO.gif' />";
        $("#card-container").html(htmlLoad);
  });
});
```

How do I organize this data for this loop to happen?

I try alert "alert(json[0]);" and this was the result:

[image]

This is my PHP page:

```
<?php
require 'conexao.php';

if($_POST['ordFilter'] == 200){
  $selectNegociacaoASC = 'SELECT * FROM wp_crm_contacts WHERE user_id = '.$userId.' AND status is NULL ORDER BY name ASC;';
  $stmtNegociacaoASC = $db->prepare($selectNegociacaoASC);
  $response = $stmtNegociacaoASC->execute();
  $resultNegociacaoASC = $stmtNegociacaoASC->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $countNegociacaoASC = count($resultNegociacaoASC);

  for($y = 0;$y < $countNegociacaoASC; $y++){
    $name[$y] =  $resultNegociacaoASC[$y]['name'];
    if($name != ""){
      echo json_encode($name);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Who is giving that response data? If they're within your control, I'd just fix it before sending. That data is a mess. It appears to just be a whole bunch on lists without a parent container. Idk how you'd easily make that a valid JSON.

Comment: Hi @Carcigenicate , I edited the question.

Comment: You can't echo more than once. What you are sending is not a valid structure. Create your array within the server side loop and send that array after loop completes

Comment: Yes. if you echo more then once you cant get the json input in the Jqury, for instead you just store the name in to an array at the end of for loop just echo it as json encode

Answer (score 0):

PHP :
here i stored your name object into returnarray array variable then i just return the output as json.

```
$returnarray= array();
for($y = 0;$y < $countNegociacaoASC; $y++){
$name[$y] =  $resultNegociacaoASC[$y]['name'];
if($name != ""){
  $returnarray[]=$name;//storing name object into array
}
echo json_encode($returnarray);
```

In JQuery - i just convert the json as javascript object and consoled it

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: theme_url + '/helpers/filter_index.php',
type: 'POST',
dataType: "text",
data: {ordFilter:value}
}).done(function(data){
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(json) // You can get the object now 
}
```

Try this let me know your comments